# Creating XML using the from XML clause using SQL 2000

Tags: sql, xml

I am creating an XML document from a SQL query and i was wondering if there is a way to output the version and encoding tag via the SQL Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FOR XML was new in SQL Server 2005, right?  So you'd have to manually assemble the XML:

```
select 
   '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>' + char(13) + char(10) +
   '<root>' + char(13) + char(10) +
   '    <value>' + yourtable.yourfield + '</value>' + char(13) + char(10) +
   '</root>' + char(13) + char(10)
from yourtable
where id = 1
```

It's up to you to transmit it in the encoding you claim in the XML header.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can manually prepend this information to the query result as they are no more than two strings.